# Cant fix Cryptiles - Insufficient entropy error

Tags: node.js, heroku, npm, npm-audit

Trying to deploy a nodejs app to Heroku

From npm audit i am getting an error Cryptiles - insufficient entropy error, it is apparently patched in version 4.1.2 so i tried to install that with "npm i cryptiles@4.1.2" but the error remains.

I also installed @hapi/cryptiles without any luck.

Wondering if there is something else i can do about this error?

```
  High            Insufficient Entropy

  Package         cryptiles

  Patched in      >=4.1.2

  Dependency of   node-modules

  Path            node-modules > request > hawk > cryptiles


  More info       https://npmjs.com/advisories/1464
```